# Dynamics 365: Fill field value in a popup window

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I have created a popup window to remind users that they have to fill a field value to proceed, like this:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkkZV.png

I would like to add this field in the popup window, so users can fill the value of this optionset like below:
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwniw.png

and this value to be filled in form too. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remind users to fill the field, better to make the field mandatory rather than asking in dialog. Also the 2nd screenshot you added is of a different form i.e.
Eg: 1) On Opportunity - > click won -> this opens Opportunity Close form (a different entity)
2) Case -> Resolved -> this opens Case resolution form

Hence if you really want to show as dialog, use [Open webresource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/xrm-navigation/openwebresource)

Comment: Yes, I know about the 2nd picture, I added it as a reference. I will try with openWebResource